# Hang Up / Disconnect / End Call Programmatically using Swift iOS 8/9

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

As the topic suggests, is there any way to hang up / disconnect / end a phone call in progress programmatically from my application? If not, how does it work with Bluetooth devices? Most Bluetooth devices you press once to answer the incoming call and then you can press again to end the call. How does this work?

Thank you.

Comment: Most important you can' touch sms, message, phone api provided by Apple. You can create you own interface for connecting/disconnecting call from you app but Apple does not allow any app to disconnect  running phone call on you phone.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Is it possible to create my own interface that does what Phone app does in iOS when user uses the phone?

Comment: you can't even do it from your own interface. Apple does not allow disconnecting any ongoing call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth headsets are supported/implemented by the OS for the specific function they are designed to fulfill (answering / hanging up calls, etc).  They are not apps and do not utilize the SDK as apps do.  As @Gagan_iOS indicates in his comment, the SDK does not provide any functionality for an app to interfere with an ongoing phone call in any capacity.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in any version of iOS.
All of this functionality it is part of the private telephony framework of apple. The only possible way to do this it's using jailbreak so you can hook in the call and end the call.

Comment: Is it possible to use private telephony framework to create an app that would do the same as Phone app on iOSs ... at least make and take a call and speak on the call?